# What programming technologies does this web site use?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to learn some things from AJAX and jQuery, i believe that it is a basic knowledge a programmer must have. I am a self instructed so I am reading tutorials and examples to get in touch with these technologies as good as I can.

I saw this page [www.soby.gr](http://www.soby.gr) that I guess uses a XML feed for the main content ( is a groupon like aggregator ). My question is what did they use for their menu on the left of the page. When you click/select an option, the content on main page changes based on the criteria the user clicked on. For example SPA will show only the deals having SPA.
What I like is how fast the content is filtered.

Can anyone give me some clues about how it is working and what technology is used for that fast content-changing?

Thank you all.

Comment: To start with, they are using Prototype:  http://soby.gr/javascripts/all.js?1302796655

Comment: Search and learn about caching. There are many ways of caching this, using files (like xml), or an API built in php that I can't remember the name right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very easily using jquery. There's a jquery built in function called `.load('your div content page path')` so, when you click a menu, you can just load only the particular part. following is an example:

```
$(function(){
$("#1stmenu").live('click', function(){ 
    $("#content").load('1stdivcontent.html'); 
    return false;
});

$("#2ndmenu").live('click', function(){
    $("#content").load('2nddivcontent.html');
    return false;
});});
```

Comment: Hello, I am new to jquery. What does the .live(clivk... do ?

Comment: I think this article will help you to understand [from this link](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/), but before that you may need to learn JQuery, when you use JQuery rather than pure Javascript, you can do lot more work with few lines, that's why I use JQuery here

Answer (score 1):

> "Can anyone give me some clues about how it is working and what technology is used for that fast content-changing?"

Looks like all the content is already loaded in the DOM and they are just showing/hiding with Prototype / JavaScript.

Comment: +1 - I'm sure you're right after visiting that page.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea behind how the menu works is a basic filter. For example, all the "deal items"  will be loaded initially, with multiple relevant classes being added to each item. Each link on the left will hide all the deal items in the main area then show all items with the the related class.

This basic functionality is [quite easy to implement](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/CRFSR/show/) ([edit](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/CRFSR/edit)) but more feature-rich plugins such as [Isotope for jQuery](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) exist too.